# Non-interactive functional requirements software engineering

Tags: software-design, use-case, requirements, use-case-diagram

I'm having a problem with listing some non-interactive functional requirements for building a project about "Smart food court system for a university" with self-service. In that system, customer can order through mobile app or machine, pay by e-wallet, and when ordering by machine, the machine will automatic print a bill after payment. I can't understand clearly what a concept non-interactive functional requirements in software engineering. And with the example that machine print a bill automatically after payment is a non-interactive functional requirements or not? Can anyone give more examples about non-interactive functional requirements to help me understand clearly? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The concept of ***non-interactive requirement*** is not a  common nor well-defined terminology in software engineering.

Interactive requirements are about what the system shall do in response to a user action, or to enable a user action.

Automatically printing a bill is therefore an interactive requirement: even if the printing is by itself not interactive, the sheer fact of enabling the user to pick the bill makes it interactive.

Interactive requirements are captured in the use-cases or in UI requirements. Non-interactive requirements are all the rest, for example:

- general business rules
- requirements about the data objects to be managed, about their consistency, and how they relate to each-other;
- non-functional requirements, such as operating constraints, or performance, security or maintainability related requirements.